# What are the drawbacks of numba?

Tags: python, numba

I just realized numba exist.

I mean, what the hell? Why hasn't anybody told me about this fantastic package before? Basically, if I have a slow for-loop in Python, I can do some numba stuff to it, and it runs like it's C++.

Whaaat?!

This is amazing ... but also sounds too good to be true. So what are the drawbacks of this package? Is it really as amazing as it sounds, or are there some hidden costs, or other failings of this package?

Comment: Drawbacks are (in no particular order and not all of them are equally bad of course): 1) an additional dependency 2) overhead on first compilation of the method 3) not applicable for all code -> no speedup possible + actually slower due to numba overhead 4) potentially un-python-esk code necessary to make speedup possible. But don't get me wrong. Has saved me multiple hours in the last week alone ^_^ also see [numba-docs](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#:~:text=Numba%20is%20a%20just%2Din,instruct%20Numba%20to%20compile%20them.) for when (not) to use numba

Comment: Open-ended questions which have a specific topic, such as this one, can be valuable sources of information and should be tolerated on SO, not least because it fosters the free flow of information and spites the petty bureaucrats. Have my upvote =D

Answer (score 1):

To further explain my comment - the main drawbacks are:

1. `numba` is an additional dependency
2. first compilation comes with overhead
3. not applicable for all types of code (3.1: no speedup; 3.2: does not compile)
4. un-python-esk code
5. hidden dependencies

Some examples as explanation (`when_to_use_numba_examples.py`):

```py
# 1) additional dependency
import numba as nb
import numpy as np


# 3.2) just does not work with numba
def mixed_types(n: int) -> list:
    l = []
    l.append('mixed types')
    l.append(-1) # does not work in numba -> type of list cannot be determined
    for i in range(n):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            l.append(i * 3)
        else:
            l.append(str(i + 7))
    return l


def list_math(n: int) -> list:
    # 4) allocation of arraylist is un-python-esk.
    # l = []; l.append(...) is more typical
    l = [0] * n 
    for i in range(n):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            l[i] = i * 3
        else:
            l[i] = i + 7
    return l


def numpy_code(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> float:
    # 3.2) .dot only works on floating point arrays
    return a.dot(b + 2)


# numba_mixed_types = nb.njit()(mixed_types)
# numba_mixed_types(0)

numba_list_math = nb.njit()(list_math)
numba_list_math(0) # 2) run to compile

numba_numpy_code = nb.njit()(numpy_code)
a = np.random.rand(5000)
b = np.random.rand(5000)

# 3.2) dot implementation does not work with integers
# numba_numpy_code(np.random.randint(0, 10, 100), np.random.randint(0, 10, 100))

# 5) hidden dependency sklearn
numba_numpy_code(a.astype(np.float32), b.astype(np.float32)) # 2) run to compile


print(f'numpy=={np.__version__}')
print(f'numba=={nb.__version__}')
```

however decent speedups can be achieved for *math-y* or *number-y* computations:

```py
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.22.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: %run when_to_use_numba_examples.py
numpy==1.20.2
numba==0.53.1

In [2]: %timeit list_math(1_000_000)
70.6 ms ± 164 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit numba_list_math(1_000_000)
30.6 ms ± 731 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit numpy_code(a, b)
3.63 µs ± 11 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit numba_numpy_code(a, b)
1.8 µs ± 22.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Why is numba being an "additional dependency" a problem? So is numpy, pandas, and tons of other things regularly being used.

Comment: Yeah, yeah sure. Just saying that for whatever fictional requirements that _might_ be a problem.

Comment: numba is a pretty special dependency, that can cause troubles depending on your setup

Comment: @StefanB one of the problems pointed out by you can be overcome check out [Python High Performance - Second Edition by Gabriele Lanaro](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-high-performance/9781787282896/6e5cc5c4-ad53-4657-b502-6630dd9efced.xhtml)